# Vue.js - Passing Parameters to a child route

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue.js app. This app shows views using the [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/). When the app starts, I need to retrieve a key from the server. I then want to pass that key to the child views. To demonstrate the problem I've setup this [Fiddle](https://router.vuejs.org/en/). The code related to this question like this:

```
var Page1 = { template: '<div><h3>Page 1</h3><p>Number: {{ number }}</p></div>', props: [ 'number' ] };
var Page2 = { template: '<div><h3>Page 2</h3><p>Number: {{ number }}</p></div>', props: [ 'number' ] };

var routes = [
  { path: '/page-1', component: Page1 },
  { path: '/page-2', component: Page2 }
];

var router = new VueRouter({
  routes 
});

var app = new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    num: 0  
  },
  created: function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.num = 1;
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

When I run this app, I'm not sure how to "pass" the `app.num` to the child views (`Page1` and `Page2`) when `app.num` gets set. I tried using the approach mentioned in the "[passing props to route components](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html)" docs. However, that approach doesn't seem to work for data that is loaded after creation. What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can bind values from the parent component to the child via the `router-view` like this:

```
<router-view :number="num"></router-view>
```

Comment: Awesome! I had no idea you could do that.